# How can I configure my iPhone so that applications in the background aren’t getting network throttled by iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, internet, multitasking

iOS sometimes [limits the internet speed of applications in the background](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/463496/20338).

How can I configure my iPhone so that applications in the background aren’t getting network throttled by iOS?

Comment: Disable Background App Refresh?

Comment: I think what @Thinkr is recommending is disabling background app refresh on all apps OTHER THAN the ones that you want to remain unthrottled.

Comment: @AllInOne thanks, is it because they are competing to get some "background network"?

Comment: @AllInOne Yes, exactly

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Yes, those apps are obviously running in the background, to make them perform tasks quicker, you can disable Background App Refresh for all other apps. You can also make sure that "Low Data Mode" is disabled for your network so that you can allow more data transfers. Another solution would be to simply quit all apps except the one you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All apps running the the background of iOS *will* be throttled because once it’s pushed back, it must register its tasks with scheduler called BGTaskSchuedler

[How much faster can apps download if they have the focus on iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/463496/119271)

You could potentially prevent the app from going to the background, but it would be on a per app basis supported by the dev. Unfortunately, there’s no OS tweak.